# Codename One add ios build hint subkey

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm trying to make a connection to a test environment over HTTP. This requires `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to be set as subkey of dictionary `NSAppTransportSecurity` according to [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi). How would I go about doing this in Codename One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following build hint as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085671/7114753)

```
 ios.plistInject=
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict> 
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array><dict><key>CFBundleURLName</key> 
      <string>com.mycompany.myapp</string></dict><dict> 
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array><string>MyApp</string></array></dict></array>
```